# Does generating two random numbers over just one affect the result?

Tags: random

I need to generate a random number between 1 and 52, for a card game (I know how to).

I could either use `random (52)` to directly reference each card in the pack, or I could do `random(4)` and `random(13)` to get the Suit and Value separately.

I can get the suit and value from the number between 1 and 52 with `r div 13` and `r mod 13 + 1`.

But I am wondering if generating two random numbers will affect the "randomness" of the outcome. As the numbers generates will be pseudo random numbers, so that could affect it in some way?

And if the low numbers 4 and 13 vs 52 don't make a difference, is there a value where this *could* become an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a low-quality PRNG (like your average `rand()` implementation: Sure it'll affect stuff, but not in a way which is easily predictable without knowing your exact PRNG implementation and your exact code. Either one might be "better" than the other, for some value of "better".

If you're using a good-quality PRNG: Nah, doesn't matter. Go wild.

Comment: Right. You have to assume the distribution of your  pseudo-random numbers is "good". If it is, the two approaches are equivalent. If not, you're in trouble already and it is not clear which of the two approaches would be a better mitigation/workaround.

Comment: Is there a magnitude (i.e. 2^100 or more) that would cause issues? Or is it the same?

Comment: At some point, you will be generating numbers with higher precision than your PRNG can handle (often 32 or 64-bit). In which case for each result you want you may require 2 or more numbers to be generated.

Comment: If the PRNG is capable (of producing uniformly distributed numbers across the specified range), it does not matter.

Comment: @Tim That also depends on your definition of "better", but the short answer is, low-quality PRNGs have pattern issues at every range magnitude.